# Selenium is unable to start Firefox when run through Jenkins

Tags: selenium, firefox, jenkins, automation

When I run test locally, I'm able to run all my Selenium tests on Firefox. But when trying to run same through Jenkins it fails to start Firefox and no error message displayed.

I'm using below configurations

> - Selenium 3.0.2,
> - Jenkins 1.1.0,
> - Firefox 50.0.2

Chrome works fine through Jenkins

Comment: It might be the version of Firefox you use. We are using Selenium.NET and are forced to stay on Firefox v47.0.1, otherwise we have the same problems. Try downgrading Firefox.

Comment: Is there a way i can get some logging to display to know exactly why it fails with current Version of FF

Comment: I don't want to revert back. I want it o work with current FF version. Please help

Comment: You're stuck with upgrading Selenium or downgrading Firefox. Sorry to say.

Comment: Which Version of selenium should I upgrade to in order to resolve this issue?

Comment: I get following error in my workspace geckodriver.log                             ###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x2E0081,name=PBrowser::Msg_SetDocShellIsActive) Channel error: cannot send/recv
JavaScript error: resource://app/modules/ContentCrashHandlers.jsm, line 95: TypeError: browser.permanentKey is not a non-null object
1486762992101 Marionette WARN Using deprecated data structure for setting timeoutsJavaScript error: chrome://marionette/content/listener.js, line 1013: NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005